# Margin start and end not working in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I can't seem to get why the 'separator' side margins don't work.
Been searching for answers but no luck, curious though that when I set 'mAppBar' margins, the separator margins apply too.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/mAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            style="@style/CustomToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
            app:title="@{mTitle}"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#1b1b1b"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_padding_small"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_padding_small"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mAppBar"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any idea is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing `separator` width to `0dp`.

Comment: @UndefinedBug1.0 tried it, not working

Comment: Try this android:layout_width="0dp" For your View

Comment: There's no such a thing as match_parent in constrainLayout. Either it's wrap_content or 0dp.

Comment: so... the AppBarLayout had elevation ... and the 1dp from the separator was enough for the shadow to show as a line and overlapped it, the fix was to set app:elevation="0dp". Thank'yall